# Proof related to rings $m \times (a + b) = m \times a + m \times b$

Tags: ring-theory, field-theory

I have a trouble proving this sentence, as I don't know what assumption should start the proving implication. I know what are the characteristics of a ring, but I m, n are not in the ring.

```
    a, b are in ring (F, +, x).
    m, n are whole numbers. 
    Proof that: m x (a + b) = m x a + m x b.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a ring question, but just related to groups.

Let $G,+$ be an *abelian* group (with neutral element $\mathbf{0}$, just to make things clearer). The definition of $ma$, for $m$ integer and $a\in G$ is the same as for powers in multiplicative groups:
\begin{cases}
0a=\mathbf{0} \\[6px]
(m+1)a=ma+a & (m\ge0) \\[6px]
ma=-(-m)a & (m<0)
\end{cases}

This definition doesn't require the group to be abelian. The next property does:
$$
m(a+b)=ma+mb
$$
Let's prove it by induction for $m\ge0$. The base case is obvious by definition. So assume we know $m(a+b)=ma+mb$; then
\begin{align}
(m+1)(a+b)
&=m(a+b)+(a+b)  &&\text{definition}\\
&=ma+mb+(a+b)   &&\text{induction hypothesis}\\
&=ma+a+mb+b     &&\text{commutativity}\\
&=(m+1)a+(m+1)b &&\text{definition} 
\end{align}
For $m<0$, we have, setting $n=-m>0$ for simplicity
\begin{align}
m(a+b)
&=-\bigl(n(a+b)\bigr) &&\text{definition}\\
&=-(na+nb)            &&\text{above argument}\\
&=-(nb)-(na)          &&\text{negative of a sum}\\
&=-(na)-(nb)          &&\text{commutativity}\\
&=ma+mb               &&\text{definition}
\end{align}

Since a ring is an abelian group with respect to addition, you're done because it's a special case.

Answer (score 2):

For $m\in\mathbb{N}$ and $a\in F$, the product $ma$ is defined by induction as follows.  First, we define $0\cdot a=0$.  Next, assuming we have already defined $ma$, we define $(m+1)a=ma+a$.  Intuitively, this means that $ma$ is just the sum $a+a+a+\dots+a$, where there are $m$ terms in the sum.

Since this definition is by induction, to prove that $m(a+b)=ma+mb$, you will have to use induction on $m$.